# Wish I were or wish I could

Tags: modal-verbs

Is there a big difference between those 2 sentences

I wish I were with you and I wish I could be with you

the first one means I would like to be with you but that is not possible  and the second means I would like to be with you not now but in the future..... So both express the fact that is not possible for me to be with you now

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses

Comment: **could** refers explicitly to the impossibility.  The speaker *cannot* be with the other person for some unstated reason.  **were** on the other hand refers merely to the situation-contrary-to-fact: "I *am not* with you now and I wish that I *were* with you" versus "I *can't be* with you now and I wish that I *could be* with you now".

Answer (score 3):

I wish I were with you.

I wish I could be with you.

Both sentences indicate a hypothetical situation, but there's a big difference in these sentences in terms of tenses.

The former expresses a wish for the present, whereas the latter with the use of the modal "could" expresses a wish for the future.

Answer (score -2):

In first sentence, it is not possible to be with the person anymore. There is no chance. (the action is happening now) But in the second one there is still a chance!(refers to future)